# How can I force certain applications to use specific network connections?

Tags: windows-xp, networking

### **Let's say I have two active network connections that let me out to the internet.**

I want *certain applications* to only use *Network Connection 1*, while **some others** should use **Network Connection 2**.

Is this possible in Windows XP? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: What application? I used to do this with browsers simply pointing them to the correct NIC in the Network connections settings.

Comment: Needs to be any application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/)** - Bind **any** Windows application to a specific interface (by IP or GUID).

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows
>   application that will inject itself
>   into another application and alter how
>   certain Windows Sockets calls are
>   made, allowing you to force the other
>   application to use a specific network
>   interface / IP address. This is useful
>   if you are in an environment with
>   multiple interfaces and your
>   application has no such option for
>   binding to a specific interface.

Comment: This application would be perfect, except I cannot get it to work even with the programs mentioned as compatible on the page. Firefox just hangs as if it can't find the destination. If I disable the network adapter i don't want to use, it will fall back to the other and work fine, so I know the connection is okay.

Comment: i don't use Firefox but it definitely works with uTorrent on my eee pc.

Comment: Didn't work for me on my Windows 7 machine with uTorrent application :(

Comment: ForceBindIP appears to work on 64bit Windows 7 if you put the DLL into the SYSWOW64 folder instead of the System32 folder.

Comment: ForceBindIP works fine for me on Windows 7 64 bit (after putting the dll in the system32 folder).