# How can I force Windows 7 to use specific network adapters per program?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, network-adapter, hamachi

I am using Hamachi VPN. I want to setup Windows 7 to use the Hamachi VPN network adapter for specific software on my system; other softwares should use the regular network adapters.

Is this possible in Windows 7? Is there a kind of filter system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force certain applications to use specific network connections?](http://superuser.com/questions/74389/how-can-i-force-certain-applications-to-use-specific-network-connections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the purpose of [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/)

I don't have tested it myself and it's a sort of hack so it will not work in all cases...

Answer (score 0):

Not natively no. Most programs will go with the 'default' connection. Whichever one that was established first. Your better off looking into the program's options themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You could install your vpn client and the relevant programs to a virtual machine, but that's a klugde.

There's also the good old fashioned command line route command.  Odds are the program you want to use the vpn will all be strictly talking to ip addresses in a specific range/subnet.  So you can set your routing table to use the non-vpn interface for the default route, and the vpn interface for everything in the target range.

Comment: Using ForceBindIp is against the ToS of the software that i am using and their IP range is to dynamic for cmd route command as they use a wide variety of Cloud Services which also might impact other applications talking to cloud services.
Any further Ideas?