# Binding a program to a specific Network Adapter

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

I am just using my windows7x64 desktop and I want a utility/program that allows me to chose which adapter a program uses for example, running a game through Adapter1 and Streaming videos through Adapter2 etc.

Do such utilities exist and/or work effectively?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/124223/how-can-i-force-windows-7-to-use-specific-network-adapters-per-program?rq=1

Comment: Mmm source bind sounds good in theory, however not being widely supported or used i'm sure I would get issues galore.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what your routing table is supposed to do. You specify the destination - routing cares about how your packet gets there (and thereby also decides via which interface the data gets sent). So you should probably think about configuring your routing to match your needs.

Comment: Not sure if upvote or downvote. Plain old routing tables are very tricky to use for such purposes, since you need to know every destination host you'll need, and manually add them to the routing table; this even breaks completely if both services happen to be provided by the same host. (Plus, operating systems already provide functions to bind connections to a specific source address or interface, most programs just don't use them.)

Comment: (in other words, policy-based routing would be more apropriate, but Windows doesn't support that)

Comment: Lol are you talking about my little SOHO router :D, yer I don't think she has modifyable routing tables Im not using corporate grade Cisco Routing here. I was hoping for something more application based

Comment: @bennyboy: I would think all routers have modifiable routing tables, yes. (Even Windows does.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my "Network Adapter Selector" project:

https://github.com/falahati/NetworkAdapterSelector

or the famous "ForceBindIP":

https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip