# Can I force Windows to prefer a specific network adapter for Internet?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have two Ethernet adapters with two different Internet connections on each: one has a connection to fast 4G broadband and the other has a connection to my home LAN- only I use the 4G broadband while the home broadband is shared.

I have a printer wirelessly connected to the home router, it supports Ethernet and can be connected to the 4G broadband router, except that its wireless turns off automatically (no manual override) and so loses connection to the home router.

My problem is that I need to access the printer & other services within the home LAN, while using the Internet from the 4G router. I've [read that most programs will use the 'default' connection](https://superuser.com/a/124258/300646) and **[also about ForceBindIP](https://superuser.com/a/74395/300646)**. ForceBindIP seems to offer the functionality I want but is a little extreme for my use case (i.e, I only need data from the printer service to go out on one IP, and everything else on the other, and I don't think this is something that ForceBindIP can offer).

Perhaps it's possible to apply ForceBindIP to a service?

I'm using Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: http://www.oracledistilled.com/windows/configuring-the-loopback-adapter-on-microsoft-windows/ would this method help?

Comment: Windows has two different settings in which priority is established. There is the [metric](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299540/an-explanation-of-the-automatic-metric-feature-for-ipv4-routes) value , and then there is the connection priority in the network connections settings.