# How to have an application switch between network connections?

Tags: windows-xp, networking

I want to open one application and make it use another connection (I have two, one LAN and one Mobile). How do I do it?

I'm using WindowsXP 32-bit, I would like to use a freeware application, but if you know of any software please let me know.

Comment: Why would you want to separate your internet connections? Besides, without a more clear example of what app you want to behave like this, it's a shot in the dark

Comment: @Ivo Flipse at work I cannot use my IM(I can use a companies IM, but I prefer mine). So what I can do is to connect to internet using my mobile phone. I would like to use that connection for my IM only. Please don't judge me, Its my work and my life.

Comment: I suggest you add this information to your question, as it does make the use case a lot clearer. I'm sure a lot of other corporate users would love to do the same ;-)

Comment: @IAdaptor looks like this is a question of how to set up your mobile phone as a proxy. I suppose many in the past and now, would set up their home computer as a proxy and accessed that.  I haven't really done that for an IM app. It may depend on the IM app, or they may be a great generic solution for various apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a route that directs traffic to a certain address (your private IM) via your mobile connection. See  [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [routing tables](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/making-sense-windows-routing-tables.html) to separate traffic based on destination. Not always easy to configure, and you'll first have to figure out all the IP addresses you want to keep separate.

You can use [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) to separate traffic based on individual apps. (See [this possibly-duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/74389/how-can-i-force-certain-applications-to-use-specific-network-connections).) Takes a bit of setup to make a new shortcut for each app.