# Multiple simultaneous network connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection

1. How can I create simultaneous network connection to different networks on Windows-7 using two different NIC on a PC ? (A wired and a wireless)
2. Is it possible to make an application use a specific connection always ?(For ex: Wireless)

Comment: The answer to 1 is simply connect both. Are you facing any sort of problem there?

Answer (score 0):

To echo r.tanner.f on question one, what's the specific issue? Why not just plug them in? My laptop often has a wired and wireless connection going simultaneously and concurrently. e.g. At work, to our production network and to our test environment. At home, between my route to the Internet and my sandbox.

To point number two, that's a duplicate of this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/74389/how-can-i-force-certain-applications-to-use-specific-network-connections) and the answer is the [same](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/).  An [article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/force-specific-applications-internet-connections-forcebindip-windows/) this year said it worked just fine on Windows 7.